# How to handle missing IP addresses for a ml model?

Tags: machine-learning, missing-data

I am using netflow data for a ml project that includes IP addresses. But it seems there are many missing values in IP address column. One way is to discard those, but I am trying to retain as many data points as possible since the dataset is bit small. I am wondering if there is a way to handle missing IP addresses (other than dropping those values) that anyone has used previously or that I can try out.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: An IP address is not something which can be imputed (and imputation could introduce biases anyway), so you have to design a system which can actually handle missing values. There are learning algorithms which can deal with missing values (NB, decision trees...), but this depends on the implementation.

Comment: What is the ML project? What are you trying to do? How many features do you have?  It's all about context.  IP addresses are not continuos variables so using some statistic (mean, mode etc) isn't going to work. We need some context to decide the best way.  Sometimes there is nothing you can do.